# Changing to category attributes via setup script is not applied immediately

Tags: setup-script

I want to add new custom category attribute via upgrade script and set value to this attribute for some category.

My code:

```
$that = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup('core_setup');
$that->startSetup();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$groupName        = 'Head Block Content';
$entityTypeId     = $that->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$attributeSetId   = $that->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, 'Default');
$that->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $groupName);


$that->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'head_block_title', array(
'group'             => $groupName,
'label'             => 'Head Block Title',
'input'             => 'text',
'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
'required'          => false,
'is_configurable'   => false,
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'sort_order'        => 10,
));

$that->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'head_block_title', 'is_visible_on_front', 1);

$that->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'head_block_description', array(
'group'             => $groupName,
'label'             => 'Head Block Description',
'input'             => 'textarea',
'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
'required'          => false,
'is_configurable'   => false,
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'sort_order'        => 20,
));
$that->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'head_block_description', 'is_visible_on_front', 1);

$that->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'head_block_link', array(
'group'             => $groupName,
'label'             => 'Head Block Link',
'input'             => 'text',
'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
'required'          => false,
'is_configurable'   => false,
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'sort_order'        => 30,
));
$that->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'head_block_link', 'is_visible_on_front', 1);

$that->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'head_block_link_title', array(
'group'             => $groupName,
'label'             => 'Title of Head Block Link',
'input'             => 'text',
'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
'required'          => false,
'is_configurable'   => false,
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'sort_order'        => 40,
));
$that->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'head_block_link_title', 'is_visible_on_front', 1);

$that->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'head_block_image', array(
'group'             => $groupName,
'label'             => 'Head Block Image',
'input'             => 'image',
'backend'           => 'hastens_catalog/product_attribute_backend_image',
'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
'required'          => false,
'is_configurable'   => false,
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'sort_order'        => 50,
));
$that->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'head_block_image', 'is_visible_on_front', 1);

$that->endSetup();
```

Second file:

```
$that = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup('core_setup');
$that->startSetup();
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Beds');
$category->setHeadBlockImage('category_beds_head.jpg');
$category->setHeadBlockTitle('The best bed, allows for no shortcuts');
$category->setHeadBlockLink('/#');
$category->setHeadBlockLinkTitle('Sea featured bed');
$category->save();

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Accessories');
$category->setHeadBlockImage('category_accessories_head.jpg');
$category->setHeadBlockTitle('Accessories');
$category->setHeadBlockDescription('We offer just about everything you can imagine in the line of bed linen, down quilts and pillows, headboards, legs, bath robes, and much more. All with the Ha?stens insignia. You have a personality, and so should your bed.');
$category->save();
$that->endSetup();
```

My problem: script doesn't update value for categories.
But script update custom category attributes when I run **Second file** again.

Comment: Where is first file and second file located?

Comment: @ Fabian Blechschmidt .These files were located at module data folder. Answer below help me and I move install attributes scripts to sql folder and now all works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing one is `sql` and the other is `data`? If so, it looks like perhaps data installation is being run before the attributes are set up.

I would create an initial version that installs the attributes and an upgrade that installs the data.